# python-requests keep session between function

Tags: python, python-requests

i use requests to login to a website and keep session active

```
def test():

s = requests.session()
```

but how can use the variable "s" in another function and keep it alive to perform other post on the current session ? Because the variable is private to the function. I'm tempted to make it global but i read everywhere that it's not a good practice. I'm new to Python and i want to code clean.

Comment: Make the `test` function return the variable `s`. Then pass the variable across the functions. Or group the functions that use the session object and make a class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to either return it from the function or pass it in to the function in the first place.

```
def do_something_remote():
    s = requests.session()
    blah = s.get('http://www.example.com/')
    return s

def other_function():
    s = do_something_remote()
    something_else_with_same_session = s.get('http://www.example.com/')
```

A better pattern is for a more 'top-level' function to be responsible for creating the session and then having sub functions use that session.

```
def master():
    s = requests.session()

    # we're now going to use the session in 3 different function calls
    login_to_site(s)
    page1 = scrape_page(s, 'page1')
    page2 = scrape_page(s, 'page2')

    # once this function ends we either need to pass the session up to the
    # calling function or it will be gone forever

def login_to_site(s):
    s.post('http://www.example.com/login')

def scrape_page(s, name):
    page = s.get('http://www.example.com/secret_page/{}'.format(name))
    return page
```

EDIT In python a function can actually have multiple return values:

```
def doing_something():
   s = requests.session()
   # something here.....
   # notice we're returning 2 things
   return some_result, s

def calling_it():
   # there's also a syntax for 'unpacking' the result of calling the function
   some_result, s = doing_something()
```

Comment: Thank you ! If we pass the function in the first place we can keep it and use it in another ? How to do if the function already return something ?

Comment: I've added a little more detail to the master function so you can see that the session is being used several times in different functions. If you needed it higher up in another function you could return it, or the higher function could create it and pass it down. It's sort of the unit of work pattern. Little bit complex but if you think about your functions as a tree you find the common root function that will call anything else that needs the session. That's where the session should be created.

Comment: Thank you i will use your master function example. Is it correct also to use a class , declare the variable for the class and use it thought the methods of this class ?