# aiohttp.ClientSession shared between functions

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am trying to share session between 2 functions. After logging in, I must be able to access other pages accessible only if I am authenticated.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time


class Http:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *err):
        await self._session.close()
        self._session = None

    async def do_post(self, url,data, headers):
        async with self._session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers) as resp:
            resp.raise_for_status()
            return await resp.read()

    async def do_get(self, url, headers):
        async with self._session.get(url , headers=headers) as resp:
            resp.raise_for_status()
            return await resp.read()



async def Login():
    url =  "https:/userlogin"

    data={
    'email': 'mailm@mail.it',
    'pswd': '12345'

    }

    headers={
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0',
    }


    async with Http() as http:
        try:
            data = await asyncio.gather(
            http.do_post(url, data=data, headers=headers))
            return data
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception Login: ", e)

async def do_something():

    url="https://url_test.it?IsWork=0" 


    headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0',
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
             }

    async with Http() as http:
        try:
            data = await http.do_get(url, headers=headers)
            return data
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception Login: ", e)



results=asyncio.run(Login())
print (results)
time.sleep(10)
results=asyncio.run(do_something())
print (results)
```

Successfully logged in, when I try to reach the `do_something()` function, I get a session timed out message from the function return. How can I use the same Session aiohttp between the two functions?

**UPDATE**

Obviously using the requests session in accordance with what is suggested in this post: [python-requests keep session between function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310467/python-requests-keep-session-between-function) it is possible to pass the same session in the return value of the function .

Is it possible to do the same thing with aiohttp.ClientSession()?

```
 s = requests.session()

    # we're now going to use the session in 3 different function calls
    login_to_site(s)
    page1 = scrape_page(s, 'page1')
    page2 = scrape_page(s, 'page2')

    # once this function ends we either need to pass the session up to the
    # calling function or it will be gone forever

def login_to_site(s):
    s.post('http://www.example.com/login')

def scrape_page(s, name):
    page = s.get('http://www.example.com/secret_page/{}'.format(name))
    return page
```

Comment: i get this:   `Exception Login:  https:///userlogin
None
Exception Login:  Cannot connect to host url_test.it:443 ssl:default [getaddrinfo failed]
None`

Comment: yes, of course. It is a local site. Not accesible . The data in the post function  is fake , just for support .

Comment: in order to help you, users need to be able to reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Of course, I understand it, but I sure as hell can't share the credentials for accessing the site, nor provide one for testing purposes only. It's easy to imagine that I'm trying to solve a session problem. To be able to reply from a conceptual point of view: Open the browser, access normally to a site for which you have the credentials, and access a link accessible only after authentication. Now open a new session from the same browser, do not authenticate in this session and try to access the same link . Here, in this conceptual way you can replicate the problem.

Comment: each url responds differently and will therefore pass / fail differently too. What is the URL ?

Comment: it is a local url. There is an email and password authentication form and a page that manages users. I have to create an automatism that under certain conditions updates information to the user. I can log in successfully, as the response is correct. But I can't access the admin page. I get the same error I would get if I pointed to the user management page bypassing the form authentication

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a `ClientSession` in `aiohttp` and pass it to other functions like this:

```py
import asyncio

import aiohttp


async def login_to_site(s):
    await s.post('http://www.example.com/login')

async def scrape_page(s, name):
    page = await s.get('http://www.example.com/secret_page/{}'.format(name))
    return page


async def main():
    name = "some_name"
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await login_to_site(session)
        result = await scrape_page(session, name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The session is closed after the `with` block.

To run async stuff you need to be inside an asyncronous function, so you have first to wrap the aiohttp part inside an async function and then run it using asyncio.

To run async functions. you need to call them first with `()`, which returns a coroutine and then `await` them.

If you want to pass and use the session in other functions, you need to convert them to coroutines.

After that your code should run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to exploit the potential of aiohttp and therefore async\wait. In my program, there are calls that need to be invoked asynchronously and wait for the result before moving forward.

Now this should be the same code using aiohttp.ClientSession:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import asyncio

async def main():
    session = ClientSession()
    
    headers={ "Some" : "Header"}
    data = {"username": "foo",
            "password": "bar",
            "csrf_token": csrf}
    
    async with session.post(URL_Login, data=data, headers=headers) as Login:
        print(await Login.text())
    
    async with session.get(URL_Scrape) as Scrape:
        html = await Scrape.text()

asyncio.run(main())
```

The URL_Scrape html page is still the login page (the json result invites you to login the website does after unsuccessful login request, redirected me to the login page). It is surely what you are saying: the session is closed after the with block.

How can I keep the same session active between multiple functions? Should cookies be used?